# Area under curve cyclic voltammetry within specific bound

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate the integral area under the curve for I>0 and V<0.4, I could not do it with trapz function, please help!

I have tried both integral and trapz functions but of no use! I could not attach the text file so if you need it for debugging, please let me know how to do that.

```
close all
clear all
clc
c=Constants;
F = dir('*.txt');  
nF = length(F) ;
count = 0 ;
for ii = 1:nF
fname = F(ii).name ;
end
filename = fullfile(fname);
fileID = fopen(filename);
formatSpec = '%s';
N = 1;
c_text = textscan(fileID,formatSpec,N,'Delimiter',' ');
c_data = textscan(fileID,'%f %f');
v=c_data{1};
i=c_data{2};

idi = i>0;
idv=v<0.4;
v_pos = v(idv);
i_pos= i(idi); 
% v_limit=v_pos(idv)

inty = trapz(v_pos, i_pos)


setvalue = 0.06;
[~,closestIndex] = min(abs(setvalue-v_pos));
vm= v_pos(closestIndex)

setvalue = 0.4;
[~,closestIndex] = min(abs(setvalue-v_pos));
vf= v_pos(closestIndex)
ifinal=i_pos(closestIndex)

figure(1)
plot(v,i)
hold on
hold off
grid
area=inty-[(vf-vm)*ifinal]
yline(0);

cvarea=area/1000;
qh=cvarea/c.cvscanrate;
active_area=qh/(c.qpt*c.A);
fprintf('Active surface area of catalyst %g cm^2 Pt/ cm^2 electrode \n', active_area);
```

Error using trapz (line 66)
Point spacing must be a scalar specifying uniform spacing or a vector of x-coordinates for each data point.

Comment: Please include the text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several method to compute a discret integral.

Here is the Riemann sum approximation

[image]

And here is the trapezoidal rule used by `trapz`

[image]

The Riemann sum is the easiest to compute.

You simply need the width and the height of each rectangle (so we can calculate the area).

```
%Dummy data:
x = 0:0.1:10;
y = x.^2;  
%Width
X = diff(x)
%Height
Y = conv(y,ones(2,1),'valid')/2
%Integral:
I = sum(X.*Y)
```

This method would work even if the point spacing are not uniform.